# Closedness of an operator on Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H,V$ be Hilbert spaces where $(.,.)_H$ is the scalar product on $H$ and $V \subset H$ is dense. We identify $H$ with its dual, hence we get $V\subset H\subset V'$. Let $A:V \rightarrow V'$ be a linear continuous operator with $(Au,v)_H = a(u,v) = (u,Av)_H $ and $ a(u,u) + \lambda (u,u)_H \geq \alpha |u|^2_V $ for some fixed $\lambda \geq 0,\alpha>0$ and all $u,v \in V$.

If we define $\mathcal{D}(A) = \{ u \in V : Au \in H \}$ is $$A: H\supset \mathcal{D}(A) \rightarrow H$$
a closed operator?

My idea was to take $u_n \in \mathcal{D}(A)$ with $u_n \rightarrow u, Au_n \rightarrow w$ in $H$. Then by
$$ (A(u_n-u_m), u_n -u_m)_H = a(u_n-u_m, u_n -u_m) \geq \alpha |u_n -u_m|^2_V$$
we get that $u_n \rightarrow u \in V$.

Also $$(A(u_n-u), v)_H =(u_n-u, Av)_H \rightarrow 0$$ for all $v\in V$. Hence $Au_n$ converges weakly to $Au$ but since $Au_n \rightarrow w$ in H we get $Au = w \in H$. So $A$ is closed.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that if $u_n \to u$ in  $V$ we get $Au_n \to Au$ in V'. Since in addition we know that $Au_n \to w$ in $H$ and since $H$ is continuously embedded in $V'$, we find that $Au = w \in H.$ We conclude that $u\in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Hence the operator is cloed.